# Aligning Icon List vertically in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

new to overflow and website design. I'm having issues aligning an icon list in the center using Wordpress plugin Elementor.

Here's the website: https://goldeneagleconstruction.co/

This issue is on the home page.

I've tried a few types of css codes and this one seems to be the only one that is responsive within the custom css Elementor provides.

```
     selector .elementor-icon-list-items {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
```

I'd like the icon list to align in the center of the widget block, with the icons aligning on the left-hand side vertically.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I've done this is by setting the positioning on the icon list to "Inline" under **Advanced > Positioning**.

[image]

And then in the custom CSS for the icon list, set your margins to auto like so:

```
selector {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Elemetor you can edit the alignment of an icon list.[Go to Style > Alignement > Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vuyC.png)

Comment: Hey Tim thanks but I'm trying to have the icons lineup on the left hand side. Would custom css be the way to go? If I use the alignment under style, it centers the list but the icons are off set.