# How to Center Icon list widget (Elementor) with icons aligned on the left side?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I am creating a footer in **Elementor** on my **WordPress** website. My footer content is centered. Now I want to add the **iconlist** **widget** in my footer. However, it doesn't get centered the way I want it to. I want the icons to stay aligned on the left side and the widget to be centered but it doesn't work.

See the photo for my situation:

[image]

Icons are aligned but the widget is not centered.

Comment: I think I may have answered your question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58002058/aligning-icon-list-vertically-in-wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58002058/aligning-icon-list-vertically-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

You may try creating a custom css for the icon list

```
.class{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click the middle icon in your red highlight, all the content should move to the center. If not, make sure your widget is 100% wide under advanced > position > width.